# About adding two array variables when calling a method

Tags: java, oop

I have four parts in each array. I want to add the last part when the first part of the array matches but I can't. How can I do that?

```
data[count]=new CustomerRecord(sentence);
for (int i=0; i<count; ++i){
  if(data[i].getCustomerNumber()==data[count].getCustomerNumber()){
     data[count].getBalance()=data[i].getBalance()+data[count].getBalance();
  }
}
```

CustomerRecord is an object with part CustomerNumber, lastName, firstName and Balance. After I passed the sentence to CustomerRecord, I divided each sentence and made Balance to be double and CustomerNumber to be integer.

The error Message is that the left hand side of ***data[count].getBalance()=data[i].getBalance()+data[count].getBalance();***

must be a variable.
How can I add the last two parts and store in data[count].getBalance() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value using the `setBalance()` method.

```
data[count].setBalance(data[i].getBalance()+data[count].getBalance());
```

You cannot have a method call on the LHS of an assignment operator. You need to have a variable to which the value can be assigned.

In your case, you need to set the value as the balance of `data[count]` element, so just call the `setBalance()` on that.

Comment: Since this is my first OOP program, can you help me with next problem?

**public CustomerRecord getCustomer(int customerNumber)**

Can you tell me what should I return for this? And How to I call this from the main method?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with what exactly you want to achieve and what's the error you're getting, as it would be difficult to help you out here without much info.